# How to recover the deleted the “Quick Find View”. in MS Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

IF you delete the Quick Find View of an Entity,
How to recover it please follow the below instructions

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

- First create a view and get his GUID, save in notepad, and delete the
  view.
- Create a solution,  Import  the selected entity from which you
  deleted the “Quick Find View” and Export it. Open Customization.xml and add the XML to the following path.

XML Path : `ImportExportXml/Entities/Entity/SavedQueries`

```xml
  <savedquery>
        <IsCustomizable>1</IsCustomizable>
        <CanBeDeleted>0</CanBeDeleted>
        <isquickfindquery>1</isquickfindquery>
        <isprivate>0</isprivate>
        <isdefault>1</isdefault>
        <returnedtypecode>Entitytypecode</returnedtypecode>
        <savedqueryid>View Guid</savedqueryid>
        <layoutxml> 
          <grid name="resultset" object=" Entitytypecode " jump="FieldName" select="1" icon="1" preview="1">
            <row name="result" id="Entity Primary Key ">
              <cell name="name" width="300" />
              <cell name="createdon" width="125" />
            </row>
          </grid>
        </layoutxml>
        <querytype>4</querytype>
        <fetchxml>
          <fetch version="1.0" mapping="logical">
            <entity name="Entity Name">
              <attribute name="Entity Primary Key" />
              <attribute name="name" />
              <attribute name="createdon" />
              <filter type="and">
                <condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0" />
              </filter>
              <filter type="or" isquickfindfields="1">
                <condition attribute="name" operator="like" value="{0}" />
              </filter>
            </entity>
          </fetch>
        </fetchxml>
        <IntroducedVersion>1.0</IntroducedVersion>
        <LocalizedNames>
          <LocalizedName description="Quick Find Active" languagecode="1033" />
        </LocalizedNames>
      </savedquery>
```

Save the file.
Upload the Solution and Publish it.

Comment: Best practice: Have a backup of your system first and know how to restore it, and only do your development on a sandbox system. As a secondary protective measure, export and backup your default solution before you start working on your system. This way if you start experimenting with changing XML in solution files, you have your original configuration for reference in case you need to bring parts of it back or just restore the entire configuration.

Comment: I will get backup before doing changes in solution.
Many Thanks for advice.

Comment: If change the this line
<CanBeDeleted>0</CanBeDeleted>
 into
<CanBeDeleted>1</CanBeDeleted>
The view won't be delete